# Implementing a 3D array as a pointer to a variable length array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, variable-length-array

I just learned about **variable length arrays** in C, and somebody suggested to me that I can realize a 3D array-like object in C simply as a pointer to a variable length array. A simple implementation would look as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    size_t  ii, jj, kk,
            Nx, Ny, Nz;

    Nx  = 2;
    Ny  = 3;
    Nz  = 4;

    // initialize 3D array as pointer to a variable length array
    double (*arr3d)[Ny][Nz] = calloc(Nx, sizeof *arr3d);

    for( ii=0 ; ii<Nx ; ++ii )
        for( jj=0 ; jj<Ny ; ++jj )
            for( kk=0 ; kk<Nz ; ++kk )
                printf( "arr3d[%ld,%ld,%ld] = %f, address = %p\n",
                    ii, jj, kk, arr3d[ii][jj][kk], &arr3d[ii][jj][kk] );

    free(arr3d);
    return 0;

}
```

In my understanding, one advantage (besides of the one-line implementation) is that `arr3d` can be simply passed to a function,

```
int doSomething( size_t dim1, size_t dim2, size_t dim3, double arr3d[dim1][dim2][dim3] );
```

by calling this function in the `main` function as follows:

```
doSomething( Nx, Ny, Nz, arr3d );
```

My question now, is this a valid implementation of a 3D array-like object or will I run into some trouble ? Note that in the actual case, the dimensions are larger by roughly a factor of 1000 each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array like

```
double a[Nx][Ny][Nz];
```

then you may write

```
double (*arr3d)[Ny][Nz]  = a;
```

that is the pointer `arr3d` points to the first element of the array `a` that has the type `double{Nt][Nz]`.

So this memory allocation

```
double (*arr3d)[Ny][Nz] = calloc(Nx, sizeof *arr3d);
```

is correct. There is in fact allocated dynamically a thre-dimensional array and the pointer `arr3d` points to the first element of the array.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I just realized, I haven't checked for errors, that would probably be a simple `if (arr3d == NULL)` after the `calloc`, correct?

Comment: @Alf Yes you need to check whether a memory was successfully allocated.

Comment: Is it correct that just using the definition of `a` as you have written it in the beginning (i.e. without the pointer), so just using a VLA for the 3D array, has the problem that `a` is defined on the _stack_ and therefore much more limited in size, or is that a misinterpretation of mine....?

Comment: @Alf yes. Definition `double a[Nx][Ny][Nz];` creates an VLA with *automatic* storage, usually taken from limited stack. Automatic VLAs are usually bad idea, prefer dynamic ones allocated with malloc/calloc